# A measure on a ring is finite if it is a $\sigma$-measure

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure on a ring $R$ and consider the extended measure $\overline{\mu}$ on its $\sigma$-ring $\sigma(R)$. I have the statement

> Every set in $\sigma(R)$ can be covered by a countable union of sets in $R$; moreover, every set in $R$ is a countable union of sets in $R$ on which $\mu$, and therefore $\overline{\mu}$, is finite.

How can it be that $R$ is finite? I know that for $E\in R$, $\sigma$-finite"ness" implies $E = \cup_k E\cap F_k$, for $F_k\in R$ and $\mu(F_k)<\infty$. Now, if I take $R=\mathbb{R}$, this set is $\sigma$-finite, but it is not finite.